# Mongoose connect but doesn't record documents

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN application and I am trying to execute a job every X seconds that updates my DB. But, as first sprint, I am trying to launch a couple of queries just when I start express server (one for populate and another to list). Here is my code:

```
// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
[....]
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

// configuration =================

// connect to mongoDB database on localhost
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/dv_db_admin');
connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
connection.once('open', function () {
    console.info('connected to database dv_db_admin')
});

[...express stuff...]

// define model =================
var CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    icaoCode : String,
    documents : [String]
});

var Country = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
var country = new Country({
    name : 'Afghanistan',
    icaoCode : 'AFG',
    documents : []
});

country.save(function(err, country) {
    if (err) console.log("Error:",err);
    console.log("Saved:",country);
});
console.log("After save");
Country.findOne({}, function(err, country) {
    if (err) console.log("Error:",err);
    console.log("Load:",country);
});
console.log("After find");

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
// load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

When I launch it, I have the following log output:

```
C:\Mercurial\DV-DB-Catalog>npm start

> dv-db-catalog@1.0.0 start C:\Mercurial\DV-DB-Catalog
> node server.js

After save
After find
App listening on port 8080
connected to database dv_db_admin
```

As you can see, there is no log about saved or list executions. I've run mongo shell and executed `show dbs` but it didn't appear.

Anybody knows what's happening?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I am running on background mongo service. When I start express server, Mongo log shows the following:

```
2016-04-15T12:00:50.876+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50766 #71 (3 connections now open)
2016-04-15T12:00:50.877+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50767 #72 (4 connections now open)
2016-04-15T12:00:50.878+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50768 #73 (5 connections now open)
2016-04-15T12:00:50.881+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50769 #74 (6 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all of your calls to MongoDB in the `connection.once` callback. It looks like you are trying to save/load data from MongoDB before you have connected:

```
connection.once('open', function () {
    console.info('connected to database dv_db_admin')

    // define model =================
    var CountrySchema = new Schema({
        name : String,
        icaoCode : String,
        documents : [String]
    });

    var Country = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
    var country = new Country({
        name : 'Afghanistan',
        icaoCode : 'AFG',
        documents : []
    });

    country.save(function(err, country) {
        if (err) console.log("Error:",err);
        console.log("Saved:",country);
    });
    console.log("After save");
    Country.findOne({}, function(err, country) {
        if (err) console.log("Error:",err);
        console.log("Load:",country);
    });
    console.log("After find");

});
```

Comment: Hi Mark! Well... @Zanon answered me a similar question (but after he deleted it), but it looks that didn't work either... Thanks for your answer!